# How to sort date field in Solr?

Tags: apache, solr

I have a field in Solr called `date`, and the type is: `pdate`, with the next format: `2017-12-19T06:45:00Z`.

Then when I realize a query with the sort `ASC` I receive this error from solr:

> unexpected docvalues type SORTED_NUMERIC for field 'date' (expected=NUMERIC)

I have tried to change the type and all the parameters to solve it, but nothing works.

Someone have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you reindexed after changing the type / upgrading Solr?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by defining date type field in config.xml file.

```
<field name="publishedon" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
```

Then you can apply sorting on this defined field like this:

```
public Page<Article> getArticles(final String querySolr, final Pageable page) {
    Query querySolrObj = new SimpleQuery(querySolr);
    Sort publishedOnSorting = new Sort(Direction.ASC, "publishedon");
    querySolrObj.addSort(publishedOnSorting);
    querySolrObj.setPageRequest(page);
    Page<ArticleSE> result = executeNativeQuery(querySolrObj);      
    return result;
}
```